# how to show NSLog in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have put a bunch of NSLog statements in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest in my iOS app delegate. When I initiate an action from apple watch that calls handleWatchKitExtensionRequest, it does the action but all of the print outs that I have put for debugging purposes never show up in Xcode. I believe this is because the simulator is running watch app at that time. It is frustrating not knowing what going on at the iphone end of things.

Is there a way to show those debug statements?

Answer (score 0):

To look the NSLogs in your console, you should attach your iOS app also going to Debug->Attach to process and select your iOS app which should be running at that time.

[image]

If you follow the above steps, you will see both iPhone app and applewatch running in debug navigator, and you will see the NSLogs.

[image]

Comment: i did the exact steps above with my watch app. but it does not work

Comment: do you see both iPhone app and Applewatch running in the the debug navigator?

Comment: yes I do. This is what I did, i launched the app on the watch simulator first. once it came up and then did a debug attach to iOS simulator. i saw both of them like you had shown. But the Xcode log console was empty. It stopped showing any logs from watch or iphone

Comment: handleWatchKitExtensionRequest is launched when you call  openParentApplication. Are you sure you are calling [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:dictionary reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error){....}];   from Applewatch?

Comment: It's worth noting that attaching to a process doesn't redirect console output.

Comment: I couldn't see the nslogs / use breakpoints of the iPhone app,  until i attached the iPhone app process.   See this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/94672/watchkit-faq   "How can I run and debug both the iPhone app and the Apple Watch app at the same time using the simulators?"

Answer (score 0):

1. Run watch app.
2. Open from the simulator you iOS app
3. Attach the debugger to the iOS app
4. Finally execute the code that calls handleWatchKitExtensionRequest on your watch.

It's all in executing in the correct order.